# Radio group button validation setOnCheckedChangeListener in list view

Tags: android

I guys sorry I am new to android. Need help in radio button validation. I have two radio button yes or no. When i click on submit it gives me value which user has selected yes or no. I want to make sure user should select any one of the radio button yes or no before clicking on submit button. More details instead on giving me "not attempted" I want user to give yes or no only.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
String[] questionsList;
LayoutInflater inflter;
public static ArrayList<String> selectedAnswers;

public CustomAdapter(Context applicationContext, String[] questionsList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.questionsList = questionsList;
    selectedAnswers = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < questionsList.length; i++) {

        selectedAnswers.add("Not Attempted");

    }
    inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return questionsList.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.list_items, null);
    TextView question = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.question);
    RadioButton yes = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.yes);
    RadioButton no = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.no);
    RadioGroup rg =(RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.radio_group1);
    yes.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked)
                selectedAnswers.set(i, "Yes");
        }
    });
    no.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked)
                selectedAnswers.set(i, "No");

        }
    });
```

Thank you

Comment: take a interger variable as 0, if radio but clicked on Yes set 1 if clicked on No set 2.  At last on submitting for check values of integer variable if is still 0 then print error as select radio button

Comment: So what's with your problem? Did my answer helped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using a [checkbox](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/checkbox) instead of two buttons.

When the user clicks on submit, you use CheckBox.isChecked() to define the user answear.
If isChecked return true, then its a yes, otherwise, its no.

Answer (score 1):

Just make your submit button disabled, and then in your radiobutton change listener make it enabled:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setEnabled(false); // disabled
button.setEnabled(true);  // enabled
```